# IOS7 style inline picker with Titanium

Tags: ios7, titanium, inline, picker

Has anyone achieved to implement an IOS7 style inline picker in Titanium? I would be thankful for any hints or demos.

As e.g. in the calendar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUDZK.png

This is my current code:

```
var HintTextArea = require('hinttextarea');

var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backButtonTitle: '',    
    title: L('addwish_title'),  
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    layout: 'vertical',
});

var title = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText: L('addwish_title'),
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_NONE,
    color: 'black',
    top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40,
    width: 270, 
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    suppressReturn: true            
});
var rowTitle = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({touchEnabled: false}); 
rowTitle.add(title);

var category = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: L('addwish_category'),
    touchEnabled: false,
    color: 'black',
    top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40,
    width: 270, 
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE  
}); 
var rowCategory = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({}); 
rowCategory.add(category);

var categoryPicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    //visible: false,
    selectionIndicator: true,
    //height: 0
});
var data = [];
data[0]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Bananas'});
data[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Strawberries'});
data[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Mangos'});
data[3]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Grapes'});
data[4]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Bananas'});
data[5]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Strawberries'});
data[6]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Mangos'});
data[7]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'Grapes'});

categoryPicker.add(data);   

categoryPicker.setSelectedRow(0, 3);

var rowPicker = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({touchEnabled: false});    
rowPicker.add(categoryPicker);  

var description = HintTextArea.createTextArea({
    color: 'black',
    font: {fontSize: 16},
    top: 10, left: 39,
    height: 180,
    width: 272,
    suppressReturn: true
}); 
var rowDescription = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({touchEnabled: false});   
rowDescription.add(description);    

var footerView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE
});

var addWishButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: L('addwish_add_button'),
    height: 20,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 5
});
footerView.add(addWishButton);  

// now add the complete tableview form
var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  data: [rowTitle, rowCategory, rowDescription],
  footerView : footerView,
  allowsSelection: false
});
self.add(tableView);


// *** EVENTS

category.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug('category event');
    // check if the picker is already visible
    tableView.insertRowAfter(1, rowPicker);

});

self.open();
```

Comment: You should provide, some code example showing how you tried to solve a problem and what you achieved, so it will be easier to provide good answer.

Comment: I have added my current code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add event listener to Label view which has property `touchEnabled` set to false. Change it to:

```
var category = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: L('addwish_category'),
    color: 'black',
    top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40,
    width: 270,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE
});
```

and also event listener to:

```
// *** EVENTS
var pickerEnabled = false;
category.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug('category event');
    // check if the picker is already visible
    if (pickerEnabled) {
        tableView.deleteRow(rowPicker);
        pickerEnabled = false;
    } else {
        tableView.insertRowAfter(1, rowPicker);
        pickerEnabled = true;
    }
});
```

There is some issue with `click` event on Label in TableView but `singletap` works fine.

Also I added simple `if` statement, which will prevent adding second picker to table.

Comment: Thank you. But the click event is not really the issue. My main problem is still the exact positioning of the picker underneath of the label :-(